# WPF datepicker control to save in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

in my wpf app, i am using datepicker control to select dates which is shown below:

```
<DatePicker Name="dtpSales" Grid.Row="3" SelectedDate="{Binding SalesDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue ={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}}" Width="200" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,7,0,5" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

And I am able to save the date in mm-dd-yyyy format. How do i save it in 25-05-2019 format ??? The binded SalesDate is a DateTime datatype.

EDITED : I have a date object with value 12-02-2019 (dd-MM-yyyy) and it is saved to sql server table as 2019-12-02 (yyyy-dd-MM). When i retrieve the date from the database, the value of the date will be 02-12-2019 (MM-dd-yyyy). And Now I want to add 4 months to that date.

```
        int salesid = (int)dr["SalesID"]; // dr is the datarow
        DateTime salesdate = (DateTime)dr["SalesDate"];
        string sdate = salesdate.AddMonths(4).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateTime servicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate); // 2020-12-02
```

When I am adding 4 months to 02-12-2019, it will become 2020-12-02 ???
I am not able to get the correct date when i am adding just 4 months to 02-12-2019.

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630318/c-sharp-and-date-picker-how-to-change-format

Comment: Save to where? A `DateTime` object has no specific format.

Comment: `DateTime` objects don't have a format; their `string` representations do. If possible, it's usually better to save it as a `DateTime`. Do you want to save it as a string?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @Kuttan: Why don't you save the date as a date in SQL Server...?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: It appears from the comments that your database is already returning a DateTime object. The below should be enough:

```cs
int salesid = (int)dr["SalesID"]; // dr is the datarow
DateTime salesdate = (DateTime)dr["SalesDate"];
DateTime servicedate = salesdate.AddMonths(4); // 2020-12-02
```

(Thank you Chris Dunaway for suggesting improvements)

Comment: error throws at this line DateTime salesdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(dr["SalesDate"].ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); The error ssays "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: What exactly is your database returning? I have tested this with the following string: `"02-12-2019"` and this works

Comment: the database returns 02-12-2019. But the line DateTime salesdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(dr["SalesDate"], "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); throws error and it says the datarow has invalid dataformat. So I added .ToString() to dr["SalesDate"]. Again it threw exception.

Comment: Converting a `DateTime` to a `string` and then back to a `DateTime` makes no sense.  Why not just do `DateTime servicedate = salesdate.AddMonths(4);`?

Comment: If what your saying is `dr["SalesDate"]` is equal to `"02-12-2019"` in the debugger when it hits that line then I'm not sure where the issue is

Try pasting this line where the date is passed directly as a string and run it just to ensure your debugger is working correctly: `DateTime salesdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("02-12-2019", "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: you could do this but the issue is with Line 2 in actually reading the date in correctly from the database

Comment: `DateTime` _has no format_.  Your conversion to `string` and then back to `DateTime` accomplishes exactly nothing.  It's an extra step that is not needed.  Also calling `Convert.ToDateTime` on the result of `DateTime.ParseExact` makes no sense either.  `ParseExact` returns a `DateTime`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I agree with you on this but making this change to the answer right now isn't solving the OP's immediate problem

Comment: The OP needs to clarify what the data type in `dr["SalesDate"]` is.

Comment: Again it throws exception "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime" when reaching the the second line  DateTime salesdate1 = (DateTime)dr["SalesDate"];
            DateTime salesdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(salesdate1.ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: Try the edited answer, maybe that will help. Could you show what exactly `dr["SalesDate"]` contains?

Comment: @Kuttan: Your saying it failed on the second line? I believe your database is returning a DateTime object already. Can you confirm if `salesdate1` has the correct date already in it before reaching line 2?

Comment: dr["SalesDate"] contains 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 in the DB. its a datetime type.Yes it contains the value before reaching the 2nd line.

Comment: @Kuttan in that case try just importing it to a DateTime like you have done already and adding 4 months, remove all conversions to string as they are unnecessary. I'll update the answer

Comment: @JacobJAShanks boss i used ur updated code. it will not work. because the second line DateTime salesdate = dr["SalesDate"] needs a data conversion. dr["SalesDate"] always returns an "object" type. so it needs to converted to datetime type. if so, it will not work. any other idea ???

Comment: @Kuttan I'll add the data converter, Looks like I missed that out

Comment: @JacobJAShanks hi boss, i have already used the same datetime converter. it will not work. the code DateTime salesdate = (DateTime)dr["SalesDate"] returns 02-12-2019 (dd-MM-yyyy) format. when we add 4 months to that date, it becomes 02-04-2020 (dd-MM-yyyy) format. this is wrong.Here we are expecting 12th Feb 2019.

Comment: That's correct though?

Your SQL stores `2019-12-02 00:00:00.000`. SQL formats DateTime Objects like this: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`.

So the Date in your Database is the 2nd December 2019, 4 months laters makes it 2nd April 2020, aka 02-04-2020. Your code is correct, I think you just need to tweak the data in your database

Comment: @Kuttan: please refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) for the DateTime formatting in SQL